# Throwing an exception from a throw expression

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, c++17

Running the following code on clang exits with a segmentation fault

```
#include <stdexcept>

int foo() {
    throw std::runtime_error{{}};
}

int main() {
    try {
        throw foo();
    } catch (...) {}
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/PrLRJyHq9o2K5Eez

But this runs fine on gcc https://wandbox.org/permlink/ORV2B5RfTl22RKxo. Reading the standard does not seem to explicitly say this sort of thing is invalid. Is clang wrong here?

Comment: May or may not be a clang compiler bug per se, but the bug might be in the C++ library that compiled code gets linked to.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sure but that's almost always assumed by default in questions like this? Like the library vs compiler distinction is not too important here. The platform doing the wrong thing is what I'm concerned about. As in I want to figure out whether this is correct or whether the platform is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constructor of `std::runtime_error` is expecting a `std::string` or `const char*`. When you construct `std::runtime_error{{}}`, the result is passing `nullptr` as a `const char*`, which is probably causing UB when `std::runtime_error` tries to copy the string.

Replacing `std::runtime_error` with a dummy type that is similarly constructible does not result in a crash.

```
class X {
public:
    X(const std::string&){ std::cout << "const std::string&\n"; }
    X(const char*){ std::cout << "const char*\n"; }
};

int foo() {
    throw X{{}};
}

int main() {
    try {
        throw foo();
    } catch (...) {}
}
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8pe0YdfVeCySLV5o)

Comment: Then is this a gcc bug?

Comment: Ah, I didn't even know std::runtime_error::runtime_error had two overloads! I thought it was only constructible from std::string.. Thanks! @0x499602D2 no, a segmentation fault is not guaranteed, usually it results from undefined behavior, but UB does not necessarily have to produce a segfault.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I think not. [The standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/std.exceptions#runtime.error) suggests the argument passed to `runtime_error(const char*)` shall be fit for `std::strcmp`, which `nullptr` is not.

Comment: @0x499602D2 - No, it's not a gcc bug.   If behaviour is undefined, every implementation (gcc or clang, in your case) is free to do what it likes.   It doesn't mean the code is required to crash when executed.   It *can* result in a crash.  It can also mean running in a way that you consider is "correct"  (however you define "correct").    It can even mean functioning "correctly" with one version of the compiler, and then crashing when a new version of the same compiler is installed.

Comment: It would be good to explain why the `const char*` overload is selected here.